# Can't add Laravel Box to Vagrant

Tags: git, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been trying to install Laravel Homestead but it seems that I got stuck for several hours now. I followed the instructions [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead). I was able to edit the homestead.yaml and edit the paths for windows 7. I am using Git Bash to run everything so when I type `$ vagrant up` I get a whole bunch of errors.

```
c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>
): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line
12 column 5 (Psych::SyntaxError)
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse
_stream'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse
'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'

        from c:/users/Designer1/Desktop/Code/Vagrantfile:17:in `block in <top (r
equired)>'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:97:in `each'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:94:in `each'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/c
onfig/loader.rb:94:in `load'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/v
agrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:691:in `new'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:691:in `vagrantfile'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:441:in `host'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:207:in `block in action_runner'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:33:in `call'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:428:in `hook'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/e
nvironment.rb:673:in `unload'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/va
grant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
        from c:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/va
grant:177:in `<main>'
```

If anyone knows what am I doing wrong please help!

Comment: You you post your Homestead.yml file? I looks like you have a syntax error, specifically a missing hyphen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic indentation for .travis.yml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104917/automatic-indentation-for-travis-yml)